# 'Mail Van Key' from under dead body on a bridge

Tags: dying-light, dying-light-the-following

I was just wandering about in 'The Following' and stumbled across a dead body on a bridge. I was able to roll over the body, and underneath were a set of keys. I picked them up and it said, 'Obtained Keys to Mail Van'.

I've already completed the game and this is not related to the side quest 'Going Postal'. I also do not think it is related to the Easter Egg ending. And it is not a missing person body to ID.

**Does anyone happen to know what this key is to? I can't find anything online about this key.**

Perhaps it's just reset from the 'Going Postal' mission but I don't recall having to get a key on a bridge for that mission.

I believe this is the location I was around:

[image]

Comment: I want to say it's just for that quest. Perhaps this key is one of the two, allowing you to enter the van without the quest?

Comment: Was the bridge you were on happen to be the same one where the mail van is for the quest? If it was, it wouldn't surprise me that a nearby body had the key for it.

Comment: I can try and double check but I didn't think they were related.. I have already finished everything so I'm not sure why it would respawn or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this question was asked in a playthrough of the game on PC. I recently got the game again on PS4 to play with a different group of people and just got to the 'Going Postal' quest again.

After some deduction I feel comfortable concluding that **this was just a reset of the character** since I had beaten the game and it was not supposed to happen. As this instance of rolling a body over and retrieving a mail van key is exactly from the quest.